# Making progress bar with 3 differents color using checked radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button, progress-bar

I would like to build a progress bar with 3 colors red, yellow, and green. Each color is linked to "not done" for red, "done with difficulties" for yellow, and "successfully done" for green.

I already built my radio button.

I would like that at the begin every red radio button are checked, so the progress bar would be 100% red and 0% both for yellow and green.
Then when you check the yellow or green button, the progress bar update and win a percentage in one of those two colors based on the number of exercises.

Here is my code for the radio button.

https://codepen.io/servan-patier/pen/bGWZVQJ

````
<div>
 <input class="radio red" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1.1" checked>
 <input class="radio yellow" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio2" >
 <input class="radio turq" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio3" >
  <label for "radio3"> Exercise 1<label>
</div>
    
<div>
  <input class="radio red" type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio4" checked>
  <input class="radio yellow" type= "radio" name="radio2" id="radio5" >
  <input class="radio turq" type= "radio" name="radio2" id="radio6" >
    <label for "radio6" display:"inline-block"> Exercise 2<label>
</div>
     
body { margin: 20px 50px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
p { margin: 0; }

input[type="radio"] {
  margin-top: 7px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
      display: inline-block;
      font: Arial;
    }    

/* Main Colors
===============================*/
.turq {background:#16A085;}
.turq:checked {background:#1ABC9C;}
.turq:hover {background:#1ABC9C;}

.yellow {background:#eeca5a;}
.yellow:checked {background:#ffdc70;}
.yellow:hover {background:#ffdc70;}

.red {background:#C0392B;}
.red:checked {background:#E74C3C;}
.red:hover {background:#E74C3C;}

.radio {
  position:relative;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:5px;
  margin-top:0px
  -webkit-border-radius:100px;
     -moz-border-radius:100px;
          border-radius:100px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.radio:checked {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.radio:checked:after{
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  background:transparent;
}

.radio:after {
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:#fff;
  content:"";
  -webkit-border-radius:100px;
     -moz-border-radius:100px;
          border-radius:100px;
} ```
````

Comment: So where is the progress bar?

Comment: I don't know, and I don't understand how to do it ... I won't lie, I tried to find other work but I don't find any that could help me understand how it works.

Comment: Check  http://jsfiddle.net/Ruhley/9dEpa/

Comment: Thank you, it seems interesting, but i don't really understand why there is so much css.

Comment: If I may suggest, I woudn't use jQuery for this. I would stick with JavaScript for this like you statred :)

Comment: @Paulie_D i had a new code with the progress bar, if you want to check, now I struggle with the java function ^^

Answer (score 0):

To have a three-color progress bar, in the progress div you must have have 3 separate divs with the appropriate divs for the appropriate radio buttons. By default, I would set them to 0 width and style them via JavaScript (Remember to set height in css e.g. 100%).

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-inner red"></div>
  <div class="progress-inner yellow"></div>
  <div class="progress-inner turq"></div>
</div>
```

If I understand correctly, it should be possible to check only one option per question, and in the attached code you have an input checkbox, so it definitely won't work well.
If it will be a radio, then when selecting the red option in the progress bar should a certain percentage be marked in red?

Then you have to write a function, one like you have, only when you checking radiobutton then, you need to check which option is selected ('red', 'yellow' or 'turq'), then check what is the current width of choosen element in progress bar (only in the begining it will be 0) and increase it.

I hope it helped you a little :)

Comment: Well i finally got my bar with the 3 colors inside. 
I have to follow your advice for the function now, I need to change onclick because I doesn't fit very well with the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I give some new information, I finally got my 3 bars inside the same progress bar container, everything seems to work. However, it's really what I wanted.
The main problem is that I used onclick but this doesn't fit very well with the radio button, I should indeed use something that counts the checked point then determine if the checked point is red, yellow, and green then modify the percentage.
I'm open to other suggestions, mainly because I don't understand enough things in Java.
Here is my new code.

```
    <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-inner-red" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-inner-yellow" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-inner-green" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

<div>
 <input class="radio red" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1.1" onclick="checkRed()">
 <input class="radio yellow" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio2" onclick="checkYellow()" >
 <input class="radio turq" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio3" onclick="checkGreen()">
  <label for "radio3"> Exercise 1<label>
</div>
    
<div>
  <input class="radio red" type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio4" onclick="checkRed()" >
  <input class="radio yellow" type= "radio" name="radio2" id="radio5" onclick="checkYellow()">
  <input class="radio turq" type= "radio" name="radio2" id="radio6" onclick="checkGreen()">
    <label for "radio6" display:"inline-block"> Exercise 2<label>
</div>
```

```
    body { margin: 20px 50px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
p { margin: 0; }

input[type="radio"] {
  margin-top: 7px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
      display: inline-block;
      font: Arial;
    }    

/* Main Colors
===============================*/
.turq {background:#16A085;}
.turq:checked {background:#1ABC9C;}
.turq:hover {background:#1ABC9C;}

.yellow {background:#eeca5a;}
.yellow:checked {background:#ffdc70;}
.yellow:hover {background:#ffdc70;}

.red {background:#C0392B;}
.red:checked {background:#E74C3C;}
.red:hover {background:#E74C3C;}

.radio {
  position:relative;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:5px;
  margin-top:0px
  -webkit-border-radius:100px;
     -moz-border-radius:100px;
          border-radius:100px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.radio:checked {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.radio:checked:after{
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  background:transparent;
}

.radio:after {
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:#fff;
  content:"";
  -webkit-border-radius:100px;
     -moz-border-radius:100px;
          border-radius:100px;
}

.progress{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .75rem;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}}

.progress-bar {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    transition: width .6s ease;
}

.progress-inner-red{
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  }

.progress-inner-yellow{
  background-color: #ffdc70;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  }

.progress-inner-green{
  background-color: #16A085;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

```
    function checkRed() {
  const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".red");
  const progress = document.querySelector(".progress-inner-red");
  const checklistProgressInterval = 100 / checkBoxes.length;
  let width = 0;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
    if(checkBoxes[i].checked){
      width += checklistProgressInterval;
    }
  }
  
    progress.style.width = `${width}%`;
}

function checkYellow() {
  const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".yellow");
  const progress = document.querySelector(".progress-inner-yellow");
  const checklistProgressInterval = 100 / checkBoxes.length;
  let width = 0;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
    if(checkBoxes[i].checked){
      width += checklistProgressInterval;
    }
  }
  
    progress.style.width = `${width}%`;
}

function checkGreen() {
  const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".turq");
  const progress = document.querySelector(".progress-inner-green");
  const checklistProgressInterval = 100 / checkBoxes.length;
  let width = 0;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
    if(checkBoxes[i].checked){
      width += checklistProgressInterval;
    }
  }
  
    progress.style.width = `${width}%`;
}
```

Comment: It's not Java, it's JavaScript (it not the same thing) :)

Comment: QUALITY OF CODE: I wouln't use onClick. addEventListener - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener - is better solution (But if you are beginer, and need this to work, leve it as is,, to use this in this code you shoud use event devegation -> https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/).

Comment: COULD WORK: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but on one onClick try to call all of the checing functions.